# Removing duplicate character in string using StringBuilder

Tags: java, string, stringbuilder, string-comparison

I am trying to compare 2 strings and remove the duplicates using StringBuilder..but when i run this code..it removes the first duplicate found and then comes out of the loop...not removing the second one..

```
String name1 = "alpha";
String name2 = "delta";

name1 = name1.toLowerCase();
name2 = name2.toLowerCase();

StringBuilder sb1 = new StringBuilder(name1);
StringBuilder sb2 = new StringBuilder(name2);

for(int i=0; i<sb1.length();i++)
{
    for(int j=0; j<sb2.length(); j++)
    {
        if(sb1.charAt(i) == sb2.charAt(j))
        {
            name1 = sb1.deleteCharAt(i).toString();
            name2 = sb2.deleteCharAt(j).toString();
        }
    }
}
System.out.println(name1);
System.out.println(name2);
```

Output:

```
lpha
delt
```

Comment: what is the expected output?

Comment: @JavaGeo duplicates to be removed from both the strings...
ExpectedOutput:   name1 = pha    and name2 = det.... after deleting the first duplicate 'a' from both strings..its coming out of loop..

Comment: You store the result of deleting each character in `name1` but you are overwriting this each time in the loop...

Comment: For clarification, if there were another 'a' in the `delta` string, would this get rid of the second 'a' in `alpha`? i.e. are you removing matching pairs?

Comment: @Monkeygrinder yeah..im trying to remove matching chars..

Comment: What index does the 'l' in `alpha` become when you remove the first 'a'? ;)

Comment: lph
delt   is this the expected output?

Comment: @JavaGeo He's saying expected is pha for name1, and det for name2. For the reason I hinted at ... and now explained below, the 'l' in alpha was being skipped over.

Comment: @Monkeygrinder oh yes..."l" goes to position 0...thanks Monkeygrinder :)

Comment: is my answer correct?@JavaLearner1

Comment: @Kaushal28 yup! works fine! Thanks!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is not working because every time when you delete a character from the `StringBuilder` the length of `StringBuilder` decreases. And also the index of all the characters changes.

So don't remove characters directly in the loop, but replace the character you want to remove with some other sign (here `0`) and then remove it or just don't print the `0`.

Try the following code:

```
String name1 = "alpha";
String name2 = "delta";

name1 = name1.toLowerCase();
name2 = name2.toLowerCase();


StringBuilder sb1 = new StringBuilder(name1);
StringBuilder sb2 = new StringBuilder(name2);

for(int i=0; i<sb1.length();i++)
{
for(int j=0; j<sb2.length(); j++)
{

    if(sb1.charAt(i) == sb2.charAt(j))
    {
        sb1.replace(i, i+1, "0");
        sb2.replace(j,j+1,"0");
    }
}
}

String s = sb1.toString();
String t = sb2.toString();
for(int i=0;i<s.length();i++){
    if(s.charAt(i)!='0'){
    System.out.print(s.charAt(i));
    }
}
    System.out.println();
for(int i=0;i<s.length();i++){
    if(t.charAt(i)!='0'){
    System.out.print(t.charAt(i));
    }
}
```

Also no need to convert `StringBuilder` to `String` every time in the `for` loop.

Comment: Replace is okay, so long as you **know** (within reason) that there will be no instances of the replacement character in the original String. If you choose to do it this way, just be sure to choose an appropriate character, or things may start to get a bit wonky. Just a small caveat that seems worth mentioning.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following code.
For the example 
    String name1 = "alpha";
    String name2 = "delta";

The output will be

"ph"
"det"

```
String name1 = "alpha";
String name2 = "delta";

name1 = name1.toLowerCase();
name2 = name2.toLowerCase();

StringBuilder sb1 = new StringBuilder(name1);
StringBuilder sb2 = new StringBuilder(name2);

ArrayList<Character> duplicateChars = new ArrayList<>();
for(int i=0; i<sb1.length();i++)
{
    /*For Finding duplicate in first string*/
    for(int j=i+1; j<sb1.length(); j++)
    {
        if(sb1.charAt(i) == sb2.charAt(j))
        {
            duplicateChars.add(sb1.charAt(i));
        }
    }
    /*For Finding duplicate in first and second string*/
    for(int j=i+1; j<sb1.length(); j++)
    {
        if(sb1.charAt(i) == sb2.charAt(j))
        {
            duplicateChars.add(sb1.charAt(i));
        }
    }

}

for(int i=0; i<sb2.length();i++)
{
    /*For Finding duplicate in second string only*/
    for(int j=i+1; j<sb2.length(); j++)
    {
        if(sb2.charAt(i) == sb2.charAt(j))
        {
            duplicateChars.add(sb2.charAt(i));
        }
    }
}

for(Character character : duplicateChars){
    name1 = name1.replace(character.toString(), "");
    name2 = name2.replace(character.toString(), "");
}

System.out.println(name1);
System.out.println(name2);
```

Comment: The expected output should have, for all intents and purposes, been added to the original question so things were more clear for those trying to answer. That being said, as is, this doesn't answer the question. The idea was to replace only the *first instance* of the character in name1 and the first matching index in name2. So "alpha" and "delta" would become "pha" and "det"... "treehouse" and "street" becomes "houe" and "t",  etc.